# jQuery Datepicker in repeating row not working

Tags: jquery, html, asp-classic

I have the following code which includes a jQuery date picker that appears in a repeating row.

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!--#include file="../Connections/PSCRM.asp" -->
<%
Dim rs_AddProduct
Dim rs_AddProduct_cmd
Dim rs_AddProduct_numRows

Set rs_AddProduct_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
rs_AddProduct_cmd.ActiveConnection = MM_PSCRM_STRING
rs_AddProduct_cmd.CommandText = "select t1.cn_ref, t3.proddesc, t1.qty, t1.price from dba.quotelne as t1 LEFT JOIN dba.document as t2 ON t1.quoteno = t2.quoteno LEFT JOIN dba.proditem as t3 ON t1.cn_ref = t3.prodref LEFT JOIN dba.proditem_xtra as t4 ON t1.cn_ref = t4.prodref where t2.documentno = 448353 and t1.statusflag = 'A' and t3.obsolete = 0 and t4.rber_mi_source is null" 
rs_AddProduct_cmd.Prepared = true

Set rs_AddProduct = rs_AddProduct_cmd.Execute
rs_AddProduct_numRows = 0
%>
<%
Dim Repeat1__numRows
Dim Repeat1__index

Repeat1__numRows = -1
Repeat1__index = 0
rs_AddProduct_numRows = rs_AddProduct_numRows + Repeat1__numRows
%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
  window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="dashboard">
        <h1>Technical Requests</h1>
        <h2>Document No. <%=Request.QueryString("docno")%></h2>
        <p>This document was created on <%= Date()%> for </p>
    </div>
    <div id="dashboard">
        <h3>There are no items available for coding</h3>
        <p><a href="quote-lines.asp?docno=<%Request.QueryString("docno")%>">Click here to view the full quote</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="dashboard">
        <h3>Available items (<a href="quote-lines.asp?docno=<%Request.QueryString("docno")%>">View full quote</a>)</h3>
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Part Number</th>
    <th scope="col">Description</th>
    <th scope="col">Qty</th>
    <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
    <th scope="col">Line Value</th>
    <th scope="col">Internal Req Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Drawing</th>
    <th scope="col">Coding</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
      <% 
While ((Repeat1__numRows <> 0) AND (NOT rs_AddProduct.EOF)) 
%>
  <form>
  <tr>
  <td><%=(rs_AddProduct.Fields.Item("cn_ref").Value)%></td>
      <td><a href="#" onClick="MM_openBrWindow('../Shared/extended-description.asp?prodref=<%=(rs_AddProduct.Fields.Item("cn_ref").Value)%>','ExtendedDescription','scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,width=400,height=600')"><%=(rs_AddProduct.Fields.Item("proddesc").Value)%></a></td>
      <td><%=(rs_AddProduct.Fields.Item("qty").Value)/100%></td>
      <td><%=FormatCurrency((rs_AddProduct.Fields.Item("price").Value)/100.00, 2, -2, -2, -2)%></td>
      <td><%=FormatCurrency(((rs_AddProduct.Fields.Item("qty").Value)/100)*(rs_AddProduct.Fields.Item("price").Value)/100.00, 2, -2, -2, -2)%></td>
      <td><input type="text" id="datepicker" class="datepicker"></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>

  </tr>
  </form>
        <% 
  Repeat1__index=Repeat1__index+1
  Repeat1__numRows=Repeat1__numRows-1
  rs_AddProduct.MoveNext()
Wend
%>
</table>
<hr>
    </div>
        <div id="dashboard">
        <h3>Items with Drawings not yet coded</h3>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Part Number</th>
    <th scope="col">Description</th>
    <th scope="col">Qty</th>
    <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
    <th scope="col">Line Value</th>
    <th scope="col">Internal Req Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Drawing</th>
    <th scope="col">Coding</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
    </div>
        <div id="dashboard">
        <h3>Coded Items with no Drawings</h3>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Part Number</th>
    <th scope="col">Description</th>
    <th scope="col">Qty</th>
    <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
    <th scope="col">Line Value</th>
    <th scope="col">Internal Req Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Drawing</th>
    <th scope="col">Coding</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
    </div>
            <div id="dashboard">
        <h3>Items added</h3>
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <th scope="col">Part Number</th>
    <th scope="col">Description</th>
    <th scope="col">Qty</th>
    <th scope="col">Unit Price</th>
    <th scope="col">Line Value</th>
    <th scope="col">Internal Req Date</th>
    <th scope="col">Drawing</th>
    <th scope="col">Coding</th>
    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<hr>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<%
rs_AddProduct.Close()
Set rs_AddProduct = Nothing
%>
```

I have managed to get the display picker to show on each text box that appears, but the date selected in any text box alters the date in the first text box.

How can I get round this?

Comment: All your Datepicker `<input>`s have same ID (which is not a good practise). It might be that Datepicker uses element. If so, it results in modifying only first Datepicker.

Comment: *uses element ID. SO questions tell the same: all Datepickes should have unique IDs to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

You must to change your Script Section like that

```
$(function() {
     $( ".datepicker" ).each(function () {
       $(this).datepicker();
     });
  });
```

Its Working fine